# Make cylinder visible from the inside and the outside in Unity ( Normals Issue )

Tags: normals

I have this cylinder which is part of an object and I want it to be rendered from the inside and the outside as well when I'll import it to unity.

[image]

As you can see, the normals are flipped outside, which means that the inside of the cylinder will be invisible after importing, is there a way to make it visible?

Thanks!

Blend file:
[image]

Comment: You'll need to give those parts some thickness with the solidify modifier in that case so that you have an inner and outer surface.

Comment: Turn off culling in your unity shader settings.